# Stripping whitespace and joining multiple values stored in a single key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, whitespace

I've been teaching myself python and so far it's hasn't been too bad. I reckon the easiest way to learn is to just start coding so I've come up with relatively simple tasks to help me. And now I'm stuck and it's getting frustrating not being able to figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
{0: [[1, '.', 0, '-', 8]], 
1: [['.', 3, '.', 2, 0, 0, 1, '-']], 
2: [], 
3: [['.', '.']], 
4: [], 
5: [[2, 0, 1, 2, '-', 0, 1, '-', 1, 9]], 
6: [[1, '.', 0, 0, 9, 5]], etc...
```

So I have a dictionary where each key has a value(which are exchange rates for various currency pairs). I've been trying to turn the values into a single string so for instance:

```
0: [[1, '.', 0, '-', 8]] would become 0: '1.0-8'
6: [[1, '.', 0, 0, 9, 5]] would be 6 : '1.0095'
etc...
```

After numerous hours of trying various methods and googling, I've come to the conclusion that I have no idea whatsoever on how to accomplish this. I've tried doing a replace, and various complicated loops that turn the dictionary into a list of lists with the key[value] as a list and then trying to iterate over it using a join function etc...and it all has accomplished absolutely nothing!

It seems like it should be simple to do, but I give up, I have no idea how to do this, so hopefully someone here can give me a hand.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What would you like `2` and `4` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner...

```
>>> {i:(''.join(str(x) for x in j[0]) if j else '') for i,j in d.items()}
{0: '1.0-8', 1: '.3.2001-', 2: '', 3: '..', 4: '', 5: '2012-01-19', 6: '1.0095'}
```

"writing it in a noob friendly way", as asked:

```
d_new = {}
for i,j in d.items():
    if j:
        d_new[i] = ''.join(str(x) for x in j[0])
    else:
        d_new[i] = ''
```

Comment: @Denis That's actually quite beautiful :)

Comment: @Michael No... OP might be using Py3k

Comment: Hey thanks, that works great, although I don't quite understand it! I am using python 3 for the curious. If it wouldn't be a bother, would you mind writing it in a in a noob friendly for i,j in Results.items(): manner so I can try to figure out how exactly it works? Thanks!

Comment: wow! you can use list comprehension for dictionaries !?! is this py3 specific ?

Comment: Dictionary and set comprehensions are `2.7+` and `3.0+`

Comment: That helps a lot, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {0: [[1, '.', 0, '-', 8]], 6: [[1, '.', 0, 0, 9, 5]]}
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print str(k)+':'+''.join(str(el) for el in v[0])
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to create a new dictionary instead of printing the format of one.

Comment: This is a concept, it is easily reworked by whatever and I dont think what stackoverflow is world center for homework solution ))

Comment: Fair enough but this isn't actually homework, the OP is teaching himself.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> d = {0: [[1, '.', 0, '-', 8]], 1: [['.', 3, '.', 2, 0, 0, 1, '-']], 2: [], 
3: [['.', '.']], 4: [], 5: [[2, 0, 1, 2, '-', 0, 1, '-', 1, 9]], 6: [[1, '.', 0, 0, 9, 5]]}
>>> {k:''.join(str(el) for el in chain.from_iterable(v)) for k,v in d.items()}
{0: '1.0-8', 1: '.3.2001-', 2: '', 3: '..', 4: '', 5: '2012-01-19', 6: '1.0095'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. Here chain takes care in unwrapping a list and handling empty list.

```
>>> {k:"".join(map(str,chain(*v))) for k,v in spam.items()}
{0: '1.0-8', 1: '.3.2001-', 2: '', 3: '..', 4: '', 5: '2012-01-19', 6: '1.0095'}
```

Few of intuitive approaches

To unwrap a list like `[[1, '.', 0, '-', 8]]` using [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), use

```
>>> list(chain(*[[1, '.', 0, '-', 8]]))
[1, '.', 0, '-', 8]
```

To convert a list of `int` to `str` with [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), use (Please note, it can also work with iterables)

```
>>> map(str,[1, '.', 0, '-', 8])
['1', '.', '0', '-', '8']
```

To [join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) a list of strings use. (Please note, it can also work with iterables)

```
"".join(['1', '.', '0', '-', '8'])
```

[Dictionary Comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Comment: Also my approach although I used `chain.from_iterable(v)` instead of `chain(*v)`

Comment: @jamylak: And also didn't used list comprehensions

Comment: Ah yes, I've been told they are much more readable than `map`.

Comment: @jamylak: Have a look into the second answer in this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)

Comment: I've read something like that before but i guess its also a matter of personal preference and i just thought it looks better without so many nested brackets.